# Let's get critical: Jul 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Aikido kotegaeshi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/aikido-kotegaeshi)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Allow child to progress up the belts?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5151/allow-child-to-progress-up-the-belts)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What should I be looking for in my first, trial class? [For Chinese arts specifically]](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/what-should-i-be-looking-for-in-my-first-trial-class-for-chinese-arts-specifi)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should my body type influence my choice of martial art to learn?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5216/should-my-body-type-influence-my-choice-of-martial-art-to-learn)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Proper Foot Orientation on Spinning Back Kick](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/proper-foot-orientation-on-spinning-back-kick)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Karate Kata for those recently given birth](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/karate-kata-for-those-recently-given-birth)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do Boxers and other Martial Arts practitioners deal with pain?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5163/how-do-boxers-and-other-martial-arts-practitioners-deal-with-pain)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to win a street fight without putting anyone's life in danger?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/how-to-win-a-street-fight-without-putting-anyones-life-in-danger)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What kind of punching bag should I get?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/what-kind-of-punching-bag-should-i-get)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Left handed Japanese sword techniques](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/left-handed-japanese-sword-techniques)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Comment: I would offer a bounty on the [What kind of punching bag should I get?](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/what-kind-of-punching-bag-should-i-get) question but I do not know enough to make a call on it.